# cannot send mail via 3G with outlook exchange sync

Tags: mobile-data, outlook

i have a android 4.2.2 phone. i cannot send an email via 3G with outlook exchange sync. If i try that, he will wait until its connected with wifi, and than send it.
synchonising calander / tasks, incomming mail on just 3G is not a problem, just sending email with 3G in outlook exchange active.
Gmail, internet work just fine.
the same account on IOS is not giving any problems.

can anybody help me?

Comment: Is this using the stock `Email` app?

Answer (score -1):

I would guess there is a setting issue in the APN
Check your setting in APN with you phone company

Comment: If that would be the case, incoming mail wouldn't work either, nor would synchronizing calendar and tasks – which do work, as the question describes.